# Passing variable value into a TextView

Tags: android

I am new at this world, and I just learned how to do some simple code in objective-c but now I am trying to learn basis even for Java and Android. So .. This would be simple even for me with Obj-C but I am having troubles with Java.

I'd want to show the value of the int "numCas" into a TextView so I did like this:

```
public void  casuale (View v) {

     int numCas = (int) ((Math.random()*10)+1);

System.out.println("Numero: "+ numCas);

    TextView scrittaNumero;
    scrittaNumero = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    scrittaNumero.setText("Hello!");
   // scrittaNumero.setText(numCas);
}
```

pressing a button I can see the log of a random number in the console and I can see the text "Hello" on screen ... but If I Swap the comments:

```
   // scrittaNumero.setText("Hello!");
    scrittaNumero.setText(numCas);
```

I Get errors! I know this is a noob question but I did not find a way in any tutorial! Sorry and thanks in advance!

```
08-09 05:06:53.017    7472-7472/com.ciavapps.com.onclicktest2 I/System.out﹕ Numero: 7
08-09 05:06:53.017    7472-7472/com.ciavapps.com.onclicktest2 W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000007
08-09 05:06:53.057    7472-7472/com.ciavapps.com.onclicktest2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-09 05:06:53.057    7472-7472/com.ciavapps.com.onclicktest2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ae5ba8)
08-09 05:06:53.077    7472-7472/com.ciavapps.com.onclicktest2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ciavapps.com.onclicktest2, PID: 7472
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
            at com.ciavapps.com.onclicktest2.MyActivity.casuale(MyActivity.java:60)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
scrittaNumero.setText(numCas);
```

to

```
scrittaNumero.setText(Integer.toString(numCas));
```

You're passing an int value to `setText`, so it will refer to `ids` defined in `xml`. Proper way for you is to convert that int to String and pass it to `setText()`

Comment: Appending (or pre-pending) "" to a numeric value is a hack. Much better to use `String.valueOf(...)` as it clearly shows in code what your intention is.

Comment: It just makes code more readable. Sometimes "" can get lost in formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `scrittaNumero.setText(String.valueOf( numCas ) );`
You have to cast the value of numCas to a String, because setText accepts only String.

Comment: Wrong. The problem _is_ that `setText` _also_ accepts `ints`. Look at the api. The `int` argument is the `id` of the `String` defined in xml. Your answer will work (+1 from me). But your reasoning is not correct.

Comment: @Vikram Thanks, I forgot about that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to String (now compiler won't it interpret as resource):

```
TextView.setText(numCas + "").
TextView.setText(String.valueOf(numCas));
TextView.setText(Integer.toString(numCas));
```